# Looking for methods to get the LAC/CID for nearby GSM cells

Tags: gsm

I know it is easy to get the current registered GSM cell LAC/CID information with following AT commands:

```
AT+CREG=2
OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 2,1,"0C71","2078"
```

But I don't know how to get nearby cells' LAC/CID. I have a Android APK called RF Signal Tracker, which displays following information:

```
Reselection Nbrs: 5
n0: -85dBm, CI0: 62002
n1: -93dBm, CI0: 62193
n2: -95dBm, CI0: 61537
n3: -97dBm, CI0: 61532
n4: -97dBm, CI0: 61971
```

which are CIDs for nearby cells.

Does anyone know how to get these via AT commands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing this information is not mandatory as per the GSM spec. Still, some manufacturers provide it. But since it is not covered by standards, the command and the output format is not standard.

Some modems just give MCC,MNC,LAC,CELL_ID,SIGNAL_STRENGTH of connected site.
Some others give information about neighbouring cells as well.

For example, Cinterion has AT^SMOND - a proprietary command. It gives information about connected as well as neighboring cells .

Answer (score 0):

There is command AT#MONI which is not supported by all GSM devices.

Here is some example: http://www.roundsolutions.com/forum/thread.php?threadid=2078